# What units are the cumulative response functions of a VAR measured in, and why does orthogonalisation appear to change the scale?

Tags: interpretation, vector-autoregression, statsmodels, impulse-response

There are quite a few questions on this site regarding the interpretation of the impulse-response-function plots of a VAR, but none answer my query directly.

I will attempt to be as concrete as possible. Suppose I run a VAR on three times series in levels: energy intensity(`ener_inten`), gross fixed capital formation (`gfcf`) and price of energy (`ener_price`). The time series have been divided by the first observation (i.e. normalised to some base year), and logged.

|  | ener_inten | gfcf | ener_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mean | -0.148 | 0.063 | -0.132 |
| std | 0.099 | 0.125 | 0.159 |

According to the AIC, a VAR(1) is deemed the best model. I am then able to produce a cumulative impulse-response-function matrix plot that looks like this.

[image]

**Q1.** What are the units on the $y$-axis? It is standard deviations from the mean or something else?

**Q1a.** If standard deviations, is the following description for say the `ener_price -> gfcf` plot correct? "A one-standard-deviation shock to the energy price produces a long-run 0.8 standard-deviation reduction in gross fixed capital formation."

**Q1b.** This may be trivial, but I don't want to make any mistakes: if the units are standard deviations, I guess this implies that I can transform to the units of the respective variable by simply multiplying by the corresponding standard deviation in the table above, correct?

Consider now that I can also produce a plot of the orthogonalised cumulative responses.

[image]

I am at a loss as to why the scale of the $y$-axis has changed. A tentative explanation is that we are now in "variable units"; for instance, the table above shows that the standard deviation of `gfcf` is 0.12: this seems to correspond to the value on the $y$-axis of the `gfcf -> gfcf` plot (though this does not hold true for the other plots).

**Q2.** What is going on here? Are orthogonalised response functions just calculated differently, or is this a `statsmodels` quirk?